# Trouble opening .csv files on my Mac

Tags: csv, excel-2008

I am trying to open a .csv file in my Mac, using Excel 2008.  Currently, every time I try opening the file, my Mac defaults to OpenOffice.org 3.  I never had this problem.  I always used to be able to open csv files with Excel.

Where do I go to change the default spreadsheet program for opening csv files back to Excel?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrong site - try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

CTRL+Click or Right Click on the CSV file, click on "get info" option. In the popup at the bottom under "opens with", select the application you want to associate with this file e.g. excel.

This works for changing the file associations for most files.

Comment: If this worked for you then you may want to "accept" the answer :)